# Conducting searches with REST that return large datasets?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a RESTful WebAPI for our system in .Net, when conducting a search in my client I presume that it should hit the /person route passing parameters when required to filter the data. However, the person object that is return has quite a lot of nested objects which could slow down data retrieval. Should I have a separate controller which returns a more skeletonised view of a person, should I continue the way I am going, or should I be making subsequent requests to break down the person?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no silver-bullet way to solve your problem, but there are several approaches, which could be usefull for you. However, in my opinion, your idea about optimizing the size of resource representation in search results is correct.

1. You can include the list of requested fields in filtering query. (for example, see the similar signature/approach in [ES search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html)). Many search engines are following this approach to reduce redundant response payload.
2. As you have metioned, you can break your heavy object in sub-resources, so that you would be able to include only links to nested objects inside the person, without including the whole represantations of inner-objects. The HATEOAS approach will fit perfectly for this purpose, but it will add extra complexity to your application (but the extra flexibility too).

However, you have to choose, which approach is better for your particular application, but I think, that a good starting point will be the approach with list of requested fields.